# Extracting largest element from my array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-audio

I'm extracting samples from an audio file in order to draw the wave form - I've generated an array with the samples ( waveDisplayArray in my code below ).

I wish to extract the largest value from this waveDisplayArray, what's the best way to do this?

(I initally defined waveDisplayArray like this: int waveDisplayArray[280]={ 0 };
I'm not sure this is the best way to go about this)

thanks in advance :)

```
for( int y=0; y<convertedData.mNumberBuffers; y++ )
{
    NSLog(@"buffer# %u", y);
    AudioBuffer audioBuffer = convertedData.mBuffers[y];
    int bufferSize = audioBuffer.mDataByteSize / sizeof(Float32);
    Float32 *frame = audioBuffer.mData;
    NSLog(@"Buffer Size is: %i", bufferSize);

    int numberOfPixels = 280;
    int waveDisplayArray[280]={ 0 };
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i<numberOfPixels; i++)
    {
        //NSLog(@"i is: %i", i); 
        int j;
        int numberOfSamplesPerPixel = bufferSize/numberOfPixels;
        float average = 0;

        for (j=i*numberOfSamplesPerPixel; j<(i+1)*numberOfSamplesPerPixel; j++){

            average += frame[j];
            average = average/numberOfSamplesPerPixel;
        }

        waveDisplayArray[i] = average;
        NSLog(@"Average %i is %f",i,average);
        NSLog(@"waveDisplay Array %i: %f",i, waveDisplayArray[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can sort the array with the values using NSSortDescriptor and the take the first value among all the values.NSSortDescriptor *desc
= [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
initWithKey:@"filename"
ascending:YES
selector:@selector(sortByFilenames:)] autorelease];

[myMutableArray sortArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:desc]];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have edited and posted only relevant part to find the largest value.

```
int i;
float largest = 0;

for (i = 0; i<numberOfPixels; i++)
{
    //NSLog(@"i is: %i", i); 
    int j;
    int numberOfSamplesPerPixel = bufferSize/numberOfPixels;
    float average = 0;

    for (j=i*numberOfSamplesPerPixel; j<(i+1)*numberOfSamplesPerPixel; j++){

        average += frame[j];
        average = average/numberOfSamplesPerPixel;
    }

    waveDisplayArray[i] = average;

    if( largest < average )
    {
        largest = average;
    }

    NSLog(@"Average %i is %f",i,average);
    NSLog(@"waveDisplay Array %i: %f",i, waveDisplayArray[i]);

}
NSLog(@"Largest  %f",largest);
```

Comment: Thanks Aadhira, that works well & gives me the largest value. The problem I'm now having is when I try to divide each element in the array by the largest value. I set up a new loop to handle this



                int k;
  
  for (k = 0; k < numberOfPixels; k++)
  {
   waveDisplayArray[k] = waveDisplayArray[k]/largest;
   NSLog(@"waveDisplay Array %i: %f",k, waveDisplayArray[k]);
   
  }



The new waveDisplayArray should consist of values between -1 & 1, however I obtain an array with only zeros, any idea what might be the problem?

Comment: See, `waveDisplayArray` is an integer array. Whatever element it has, if you try to divide the elements with the largest value of the array, it will become zero. For example, if you are having an array with elements 2,4,6,3. If you divide each elemnent with 6 and assign back, all the elements would become zero.

Comment: I guess if you would have `float` array, the things might be different. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks again Aadhira, that's really helped me out! there are a few gaps in my knowledge that need addressing :)

Answer (score 1):

Do you ever thought of using Apples [Accelerate framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Accelerate/Reference/vDSPRef/Reference/reference.html) for this? There is for example a function which calculates the maximum value of a whole vector (your array). 
One line replaces your for loop:
            `vDSP_maxmgv(&maxValue,   1, waveDisplayArray, 280);`

There are also useful functions for calculating mean, min or whatever. This should be a lot faster.